# Can this result in a deadlock in django + postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have two simultaneous processes that run separate transactions that eventually gets to the same code path:

```
@transaction.atomic 
def myFunc():
    object = x.objects.get(filter=sample_filter) // Assume this gets a single row back
    object.sample_property = "Hello World"
    object.save()
```

One of the process keeps reporting a deadlock waiting for ShareLock at object.save(). I assume the other one isn't reporting because it was the one that was not killed. If these processes ended up selecting the same row from X, can it result in a deadlock? I can't see how because .get() does not place a lock on "object", does it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PostgreSQL, then it is at READ-COMITTED isolation level by default. So yes, within your atomic transaction, for e.g. if you are calling `pdb` after `get()` then other code without `pdb` should wait other one's transaction to complete when it reaches `save()`. For your case, no deadlock should occur though.

Comment: Thanks, I do have transaction.atomic that I forgot to include

Comment: No problem, updated my answer to include isolation levels.